# Format Multiple Worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I'm not well versed with VBA so this solution is probably quite simple I just don't know how to go about it. I have 10 worksheets (Cost Comparison 1 through 10). I need to update them with a formula and reformat them. Currently I have the following code:

```
    Sub Comparison1()
' Comparison1 Macro to change formulas to compare scenario # to as-is
    Sheets("Cost Comparison-1").Select
    Range("H8").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(IF(('Costs As-Is'!RC-'Scenario-1'!RC)<>0,'Costs As-Is'!RC-'Scenario-1'!RC,""""),"""")"
    Range("H8").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("H8:R8"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("H8:R8").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("H8:R1006"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("H8:R1006").Select
    Sheets("Costs As-Is").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Cost Comparison-1").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=1
End Sub
```

The code above is for a single sheet only. I made 10 separate instances for this macro for each sheet. Then made a macro to "call" each of these macros separately. What I want is to have one macro that combines all this. And, if possible, if the sheet does not exist to not give the error message ("Subscript out of range) as I have been currently getting.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need a loop looping through your sheets. Please read about [loops](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/1873/flow-control-structures) and read about [VBA Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices) to improve your code. With these both articles you should be able to achieve your desire.

Comment: Thank you kindly for the link! I will take a look at it and try to work something out

Answer (score 0):

Loop through all worksheets in a workbook.

Sub WorksheetLoop2()

```
 ' Declare Current as a worksheet object variable.
 Dim Current As Worksheet

 ' Loop through all of the worksheets in the active workbook.
 For Each Current In Worksheets

    ' Insert your code here.
    ' This line displays the worksheet name in a message box.
    MsgBox Current.Name
 Next
```

End Sub

Also, you can easily change some kind of formatting in each sheet.

```
Sub change_color()
For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    Set rng = sht.UsedRange
        For Each cell In rng
            If cell.Font.ColorIndex = 3 Then
                cell.Font.ColorIndex = 0
            End If
        Next cell
Next sht
End Sub
```